# "Что" - это союз. А почему запятая перед ним не ставится?

Tags: пунктуация

> Несмотря на то что воздух подаётся только в одном направлении, шар или
> мяч раздуваются ровно по всем направлениям.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что союз другой, это составной подчинительный союз - "несмотря на то что". Запятая в нём перед "что" бывает (авторская), но не когда он стоит в начале предложения.